# @PostConstruct analog for external final bean

Tags: java, spring, annotations, initialization

I want to find analog `@PostConstruct` spring annotation for external bean. 
I don't have oportunity to change source code of this class and this class is final.

other words: how to invoke external method after bean constructing?

Answer (score 0):

If you can't change this class nor derive it, maybe a customized [BeanPostProcessors](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-extension-bpp) would do the job ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try init-method, i.e.:

```
 <beans>
    <bean id="yourBean" class="com.example.your.external.Class" init-method="yourExternalInitMethod"/>
</beans>
```

EDIT
Alternative solution might be implementing [InitializingBean](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/InitializingBean.html), but it's Spring-specific interface.
EDIT2. 
You might want to take a look at Mkyong's tutorial about [init-method and destroy-method](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-init-method-and-destroy-method-example/).

Comment: But for both, you need to change the source code of your bean's class,  and since it's final, you cannot derive it.